# Show site on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, show-hide

im trying to make a site like http://html5up.net/overflow , the one thing that i really dont like about it is that you can scroll down before clicking the  "proceed as anticipated" button . To me this kinda defeats the point of pressing the button and making it scroll for you, if you can just scroll down manually as well.

My question is, is there a way to make the rest of the page ONLY display as soon as you pressed that button, so the user is forced to press the button and see the automated scrolling before he can see the rest of the site.

I would like the same for the next button as well "act on this message"

any help is apreciated.

this is the code

```
<body>

    <!-- Header -->
        <section id="header">
            <header>
                <h1>Overflow</h1>
                <p>By HTML5 UP</p>
            </header>
            <footer>
                <a href="#banner" class="button style2 scrolly scrolly-centered">Proceed as anticipated</a>
            </footer>
        </section>

    <!-- Banner -->
        <section id="banner">
            <header>
                <h2>This is Overflow</h2>
            </header>
            <p>A brand new site template designed by <a href="http://n33.co">AJ</a> for <a href="http://html5up.net/">HTML5 UP</a>.<br />
            It’s fully responsive, built on <a href="http://skeljs.org">skelJS</a>, and of course entirely free<br />
            under the <a href="http://html5up.net/license/">Creative Commons license</a>.</p>
            <footer>
                <a href="#first" class="button style2 scrolly">Act on this message</a>
            </footer>
        </section>

    <!-- Feature 1 -->
        <article id="first" class="container box style1 right">
            <a href="http://ineedchemicalx.deviantart.com/art/Time-goes-by-too-fast-335982438" class="image full"><img src="images/pic01.jpg" alt="" /></a>
            <div class="inner">
                <header>
                    <h2>Lorem ipsum<br />
                    dolor sit amet</h2>
                </header>
                <p>Tortor faucibus ullamcorper nec tempus purus sed penatibus. Lacinia pellentesque eleifend vitae est elit tristique velit tempus etiam.</p>
            </div>
        </article>

    <!-- Feature 2 -->
        <article class="container box style1 left">
            <a href="http://ineedchemicalx.deviantart.com/art/Kingdom-of-the-Wind-348268044" class="image full"><img src="images/pic02.jpg" alt="" /></a>
            <div class="inner">
                <header>
                    <h2>Mollis posuere<br />
                    lectus lacus</h2>
                </header>
                <p>Rhoncus mattis egestas sed fusce sodales rutrum et etiam ullamcorper. Etiam egestas scelerisque ac duis magna lorem ipsum dolor.</p>
            </div>
        </article>

    <!-- Portfolio -->
        <article class="container box style2">
            <header>
                <h2>Magnis parturient</h2>
                <p>Justo phasellus et aenean dignissim<br />
                placerat cubilia purus lectus.</p>
            </header>
            <div class="inner gallery">
                <div class="row flush">
                    <div class="3u"><a href="images/fulls/01.jpg" class="image full"><img src="images/thumbs/01.jpg" alt="" title="Ad infinitum" /></a></div>
                    <div class="3u"><a href="images/fulls/02.jpg" class="image full"><img src="images/thumbs/02.jpg" alt="" title="Dressed in Clarity" /></a></div>
                    <div class="3u"><a href="images/fulls/03.jpg" class="image full"><img src="images/thumbs/03.jpg" alt="" title="Raven" /></a></div>
                    <div class="3u"><a href="images/fulls/04.jpg" class="image full"><img src="images/thumbs/04.jpg" alt="" title="I'll have a cup of Disneyland, please" /></a></div>
                </div>
                <div class="row flush">
                    <div class="3u"><a href="images/fulls/05.jpg" class="image full"><img src="images/thumbs/05.jpg" alt="" title="Cherish" /></a></div>
                    <div class="3u"><a href="images/fulls/06.jpg" class="image full"><img src="images/thumbs/06.jpg" alt="" title="Different." /></a></div>
                    <div class="3u"><a href="images/fulls/07.jpg" class="image full"><img src="images/thumbs/07.jpg" alt="" title="History was made here" /></a></div>
                    <div class="3u"><a href="images/fulls/08.jpg" class="image full"><img src="images/thumbs/08.jpg" alt="" title="People come and go and walk away" /></a></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </article>

    <!-- Contact -->
        <article class="container box style3">
            <header>
                <h2>Nisl sed ultricies</h2>
                <p>Diam dignissim lectus eu ornare volutpat orci.</p>
            </header>
            <form>
                <div class="row half">
                    <div class="6u"><input type="text" class="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" /></div>
                    <div class="6u"><input type="text" class="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" /></div>
                </div>
                <div class="row half">
                    <div class="12u">
                        <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="12u">
                        <ul class="actions">
                            <li><a href="#" class="button form">Send Message</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </article><section id="footer">
        <ul class="icons">
            <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-twitter solo"><span>Twitter</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook solo"><span>Facebook</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-google-plus solo"><span>Google+</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-pinterest solo"><span>Pinterest</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-dribbble solo"><span>Dribbble</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-linkedin solo"><span>LinkedIn</span></a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="copyright">
            <ul class="menu">
                <li>&copy; Untitled. All rights reserved.</li>
                <li>Design: <a href="http://html5up.net/">HTML5 UP</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </section>

</body>
```

so basicly by clicking the proceed.... button i want to display the banner section, with the act... button. when pressing the act button i want to display all the rest of the site.

I have it semi fixed now but after the second click i cant scroll anymore, please help, www.fenrak.com i uloaded it so u can see

Comment: Yes. You can set the body container to have `overflow: hidden;` which should hide the rest of the body and disable scrolling, and then you can use JS to show the hidden/overflown divs.

Comment: You could style the rest of the page to not display (`display: none` for example) and then change that style with JavaScript when the button is clicked.  Though you may still want to display *something* for users who have JavaScript disabled.

Comment: Sure you could. Couldn't you just hide the content, and when the button is clicked the content is unhidden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `overflow:hidden` style on the body element. Remove it with Javascript when clicking the button.

**[Edit]** Example:

In styles section:

```
body{
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

In javascript section (using jquery):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#BUTTON_ID").click(function(){
    $("body").css("overflow", "visible");
  });
});
```

(btw untested code)

Comment: Any idea how i exactly do it, im not really the brightest with code and ive been breaking my legs for a long time on this. i added the code for you.

Comment: but wont this just hide everything including the button itself

Comment: Not with the example you provided, since the button is always visible.

Comment: okay this works! i have one more issue though, after i use this and click the last button to display the last part of the site, i cant scroll in that part, the last part is a part with scrolling, any idea how to enable scrolling once the entire site is displayed?

Comment: to explain it better:

i press the first button, it drops down to the next part

i press the second button and it drops down to the next part

this part is a longer part of several scroll lengths, but i cant scroll

Comment: The javascript I provided should do. Just make sure you put in the correct button Id.

Comment: i uploaded it so u can see the problem, after the second click www.fenrak.com